# Normalize and visual representation

Tags: ios, uibutton, normalization

```
originalArray = [
"8.797974",
"36.0614",
"82.65955",
"96.93622",
"62.24878",
"27.57068",
"6.862"
]

normedAndScaledArray = [
"1.246534",
"5.109333",
"11.71156",
"13.73434",
"8.819672",
"3.906331",
"0.9722373"
]
```

Each element in the original array is divided by the sum of all elements, so that each value is within the range `[0,1]`; in other words, they are normalized. Then, each element in the normalized array is multiplied by `buttonHeight`. What I want to do is the following:

**Not normalized:**

[image]

Each box is a button and its height is `buttonHeight`. The problem is that since `buttonHeight` is `50px` the elements whose value is greater than buttonHeight in the originalArray are not correctly represented. Therefore, I normalize the vector and scale it by buttonHeight. However, the result looks like this.

[image]

Because some elements in the `normedAndScaledArray` are so small (ex. 1.24, 3.90, 0.97) although they are correctly represented, they are not visually suitable. *(Please ignore minor discrepancies in the data and the images)*

**Q. In this case, what should I do to represent the data correctly and appropriately in the given cells?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are normalizing the numbers incorrectly: rather than dividing by the sum of all values to get everything into the `[0..1]` range, divide by the largest value. This way the larges button will get the full 50 pixels, and the remaining ones will get proportionally smaller sizes:

```
 Value      50 * Value / max
--------    -----------
8.797974    4.538022011
36.0614     18.60058088
82.65955    42.63604977
96.93622    50
62.24878    32.10811191
27.57068    14.22104142
6.862       3.539440676
```